# UI Testing: Slider fails to adjust when nested in Table View Cell

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, uislider, xcode-ui-testing

In UI Testing on Xcode 9.0 (9A235), interacting with `UISlider`with `adjust(toNormalizedSliderPosition:)` does not work at all when `UISlider`is nested in a `UITableViewCell`.

I have tested in many different scenarios:
- Normal `UISlider`s not embedded in a `UITableView` work fine with the `adjust` method.
- `UISlider` that co-exists with a `UITableView` but not inside a Table View Cell continues to work with `adjust`
- `UISlider` in a `UITableView` can be uniquely identified.
- `UISlider` identified in a `UITableView` can respond to simple event like `tap()`
- `UISlider` identified in a `UITableView` doesn't work with `adjust` method at all, even when I modify the number of rows to 1. The error message is:

> Failure fetching attributes for element   pid: 24415,
>   elementOrHash.elementID: 106102876671744.43: Error
>   Domain=XCTDaemonErrorDomain Code=13 "Fetching value for attribute 5011
>   returned AX error -25205." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Fetching
>   value for attribute 5011 returned AX error -25205.}

Related discussion I found online:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/77445

I have uploaded [my code online](https://github.com/pt2277/XCTest_UITest_UISlider) too if anyone is interested in looking at it.

I have already submitted a [bug report](http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=5059599031861248) to Apple regarding this. What I am asking is, does anyone know of a possible workaround I can use to adjust the `UISlider` values when the slider is nested in a `UITableViewCell`? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this as a workaround:

```
func testSliderAdjustsInTableView() {
    let app = XCUIApplication()

    app.staticTexts["Slider in Table View UI Test"].tap()

    let cell = app.tables.element.cells["cell 0"]
    let button = cell.buttons["Test Button"]
    button.tap()

    let slider = cell.sliders["value slider"]
    XCTAssert(slider.exists)

    let fiftyPercent = slider.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0.5, dy: 0.5))
    let ninetyPercent = slider.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0.9, dy: 0.5))

    fiftyPercent.press(forDuration: 0.1, thenDragTo: ninetyPercent)

    XCTAssertEqual(slider.value as! String, "90 %")
}
```

Comment: I attempted to generalize this a bit by replacing `dx: 0.5` with `normalizedSliderPosition` but then got the same error too, but this is an acceptable workaround. Thanks!

Comment: Ok. I ended up with something like `(slider1.value as! NSString).floatValue / 100.0` in order to generalize from `0.5`.